# Enter non-ascii characters in Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion 2.5.2 Personal (the free version) on Windows 8.1. My Problem is, that when I try to enter an non-ascii character via my keyboard nothing happens. On VirtualBox there is no such problem. Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste text with non-ascii characters.

Copy-pasting text from the host into the virtual device is possible since version `2.1.0`.

Do it by perform long tapping/clicking + PASTE in the virtual device.

According to [Genymotion User Guide](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide)

> **Copy and paste**
>
> The clipboard is shared between your computer and Genymotion. Thus, you can easily copy and paste text from your computer to
>   Genymotion, and vice versa.